# Why TensorFlow Lite need android version 5.1 or higher

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I will start developing with TensorFlowLite from now on. I have a question so please help me.

I'm trying to purchase EPSON BT-300 for the development of TensorFlowLite now. EPSON BT-300 supports android 5.1. However, in the TensorflowLite tutorial "Make sure the Android SDK version is greater than 26" is written. Why do I need a version higher than 5.1?
Is it possible to develop with EPSON BT-300 using TensorFlowLite?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use tflite with android 5.1 (or other). I used [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/tools/benchmark) benchmark with android 5.1
Some constraints may be only from using some newer features from SDK>22 in your android application